# How web browser find out when user reached to custom image in web page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, events, infinite-scroll

I am developing a web site for selling handy crafts so users expect high quality images for per product. because of SEO related problems, I think about loading image asynchronous and just when user reach to per product thumbnail.I don't know how find out that when each user reach to per prouct thumbnail when scrolling page to load main and hight quality image for it; are there any event in javascript for detect that? or I have to calculate by pixels or some way like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "lazy loading". Lazy Loading means that the required resources are only loaded once the user actually needs it. In this example, the user only needs the image once the image is actually in the viewport (the elements visible on the screen)

The easiest way for Chromium-based browsers and Firefox is using the "loading" attribute of the img-tag and setting the value to "lazy". Example: img loading=lazy src="link"

This will work for most cases. However, if you want to be in control of the functionality behind it what you are searching for is called a "Intersection Observer". With this you can do alot of stuff related to elements and the viewport. E.g. how far is an element away from the viewport, or how much percent of the element is actually in the viewport.

If you want a really short 15 minute video that explains the Intersection Observer basis I can recommend this YouTube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IbRtjez6ag

I hope that this will be enough to help you with your problem!

Comment: Thanks, I already know about "lazy loading" but I want more control as you guess.